# What's the easiest way to save an object to a file without serialization attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have different kinds of objects in c# that I would like to save to a file (XML is preferred) but I can't use serialization since the class are not written by me but are from a DLL.

What is the best solution for this ?

Comment: You could leverage a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to copy to/from a serializable object then save/load that.

Comment: Be very careful if you try to reconstruct an object after doing this... There may be some kind of internal state to the object which is not exposed and therefore not able to be saved.

Comment: Serialization requires some knowledge of the implementation of an object. Without that, this could be very difficult. Instead, I would see if I could reproduce the actions I took to create the object.

Comment: Saving an object to a file _is_ serialization, by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually used JavaScriptSerializer and it does exactly what I was looking for:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person(){Name = "aaa"});
persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "bbb" });

JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer  = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var strData = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(persons);

var persons2 = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(strData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've whipped up a quick little extension method that will "serialize" to XML, given a non-serializable object. It's pretty rough and doesn't do a heck of a lot of checking and the XML it generates you can easily tweak to meet your needs:

```
public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T source, bool serializeNonPublic = false)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;

    if (serializeNonPublic)
    {
        bindingFlags |= BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    }

    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(bindingFlags).Where(property => property.CanRead).ToList();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(typeof(T).Name);
        if (properties.Any())
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(source, null);

                writer.WriteStartElement(property.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Type", property.PropertyType.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", value.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        else if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(source.ToString());
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I tested it on this class:

```
private sealed class Test
{
    private readonly string name;

    private readonly int age;

    public Test(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return this.age;
        }
    }
}
```

as well as the number `3` and `object`. The resulting XML is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Test>
  <Name Type="String" Value="John Doe" />
  <Age Type="Int32" Value="35" />
</Test>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Int32>3</Int32>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Object />
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

write your own serializable wrappers around the non-serializable classes of the DLL.

EDIT: AutoMapper was suggested in the comments and I hadn't heard of it yet, but now that I have I'd definitely use that instead of writing the wrappers myself. Unless there's some reflection required to capture some of the internal state of the non-serializable object (if possible), I don't know if AutoMapper has anything to offer there or you'd have to see if you could capture that in your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a POCO (Plain Old Class Object) class that mimics the object from the DLL returned.  Generally if you are using, I believe, .NET 3.5 or higher you have the ability to use LINQ.  I favor Linq to put objects into other classes or perform sorting or other operations on them.

Here is a simple example where you would be dummying in your return object for example.  Keep in mind in a DLL of course you could have many differing objects and do this multiple times.  I also would wrap my methods up in their own class for re usability instead of doing it in the main.  But here is a simple proof of concept

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ExampleSerializer
{
    class Program
    {
        // example class to serialize
        [Serializable]
        public class SQLBit
        {
            [XmlElement("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [XmlText]
            public string data { get; set; }
        }

        // example class to populate to get test data
        public class example
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string data { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "";

            // make a generic and put some data in it from the test
            var ls = new List<example> { new example { Name = "thing", data = "data" }, new example { Name = "thing2", data = "data2" } };

            // make a second generic and put data from the first one in using a lambda
            // statement creation method.  If your object returned from DLL is a of a
            // type that implements IEnumerable it should be able to be used.
            var otherlist = ls.Select(n => new SQLBit
                {
                    Name = n.Name,
                    data = n.data
                });

            // start a new xml serialization with a type.
            XmlSerializer xmler = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SQLBit>));

            // I use a textwriter to start a new instance of a stream writer
            TextWriter twrtr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\Filename.xml");

            // Serialize the stream to the location with the list
            xmler.Serialize(twrtr, otherlist);

            // Close
            twrtr.Close();

            // TODO: You may want to put this in a try catch wrapper and make up your 
            // own classes.  This is a simple example.
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the term "without-serialization" in the question header is misleading.

If i understood you correctly you want to serialize objects that have no serilisation-attributes.

There are libraries like [sharpserializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html) and [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) that can do the job for you.