# How can I test a "Remember Me" checkbox feature in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm trying to test the "Remember Me" functionality of a login form. I'm able to type in the user name and password, click the checkbox, click submit, and [`quit()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit--) or [`close()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#close--) the browser. But when I reopen the browser with `new ChromeDriver()` (or any other `WebDriver` implementation), the test site does not remember anything because all cookies are deleted when the browser is closed and cannot be accessed when the browser is reopened.

Comment: In such a scenario why don't you use your own browser profile to work with. In webdriver any browser launch will be like a new profile so if you quit / close browser remember me won't work. So using your existing firefox/ chrome profile will let you check on the functionality of this.

Comment: cant get you clearly bro.. is there any option in selenium webdriver or not? can you explain more. @VivekSingh

Comment: How about you go for existing profile for [chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver) and [firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787095/how-to-stop-selenium-from-creating-temporary-firefox-profiles-using-web-driver) that already exist in your local. And then check upon for **remember me** functionality.

Comment: This is that functionality of the REMEMBER ME. if that checkbox is working as fine meaning .we can go for existing profile.@VivekSingh

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: There are some related questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176528/how-to-start-selenium-remotewebdriver-or-webdriver-without-clearing-cookies-or-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455393/in-selenium-how-can-i-open-firefox-browser-but-with-the-existing-cookie

Comment: Another related question here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15594/selenium-how-to-access-the-same-session-in-a-new-window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Chrome (config):**

You have to set the path to user-dir which will save all the login info after you login for the first time. The next time you login again, login info from the user-dir will be taken.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=D:/temp/");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","res/chromedriver.exe");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Login for the first time:

```
driver.get("https://gmail.com");
//Your login script typing username password, check 'keep me signed in' and so on
```

Close the driver (do NOT quit):

```
driver.close();
```

Re-initialize the driver and navigate to the site. You should not be asked for username and password again:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://gmail.com");
```

The above can be implemented for firefox using a firefox profile.

Answer (score 2):

If the "Remember Me" feature is implemented using persistent cookies (I doubt that there is any other way to implement it), then you can actually test the feature in a cross-browser compatible way by programmatically manipulating the cookies. Cookies with an expiration date (or [`Expiry` in the Selenium API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Cookie.html#getExpiry--)) are [persistent cookies and are stored when the browser is closed and retrieved when the browser is re-opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869821/how-do-i-create-a-persistent-vs-a-non-persistent-cookie). Non-persistent cookies are not stored when the browser is closed. With this information, we can simulate what should happen when the browser closes, by programmatically deleting all non-persistent cookies:

```
// Check the "Remember Me" checkbox and login here.

Set<Cookies> cookies = webDriver.manage().getCookies();

for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {

    // Simulate a browser restart by removing all non-persistent cookies.
    if (cookie.getExpiry() == null) {
        webDriver.manage().deleteCookie(cookie);
    }
}

// Reload the login page.
webDriver.get(currentLoginPageURL);

// Assert that some text like "You are logged in as..." appears on the page to
// indicate that you are still logged in.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even though the code you provided is not complete, it helped me a lot for figuring out my use case.